# What is the default username after freshly installing Oracle Express?

Tags: oracle, authentication, credentials, oracle-xe

I just installed Oracle Express edition. During the installation it asked me to set a password but not a username. After the installation completed, it directed me to a browser window and asked me to login with a username and password. The password I know but the username I don't know.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you tried the standard oracle accounts,.. "sys" and "system"?

Comment: scott/tiger is another standard one if the default sample database is installed.